# What is the name of this specific method used to solve for the step response of a circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, current, homework

[image: Step Response Method]

I'm entering the third year of a degree in Electrical Engineering and we're just now getting to the step/transient response of circuits.

My professor is enamored with a particular method for solving them and asks that we use no other method except this one. Unfortunately this is causing issues because I'm unable to find resources that incorporate this method and the textbook we are using in this class uses another method. He breaks apart the ordinary differential equation into two, the homogeneous and the particular, in the format of Ke^(st) where K and s are constants. Oftentimes this involves finding the derivative or the definite integral of KVL or KCL loops, or using nodal analysis to get a sufficient number of equations where there is only one variable to solve for.

Does anyone know of any textbooks or resources that showcase or teach this method? Does this method have a specific name? Is my professor being unreasonable and no one else teaches or uses this method?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you asked your Professor what the name of the method is? I don’t really see a method pre se. I’m not really sure what you’re asking for. A name for the whole process from schematic to answer, or just the ODE part? Have you studied ODE in your Diff Eqs class yet?

Comment: It looks like solving using the Norton equivalent method, where a complex system is converted into a simple equivalent. The broad approach is covered in quite a few places. https://www.electrical4u.com/norton-theorem-norton-equivalent-current-and-resistance